# Excel VBA Duplicating Selected Sheets Once but then only duplicating the first sheet again

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to duplicate the selected sheets in excel multiple times however it duplicates every selected sheet once and then just duplicates the first sheet. Any idea where I am going wrong please?

```
Public Sub DuplicateSheetMultipleTimes()
    Dim n As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    n = InputBox("How many copies of the selected sheets do you want to make?")

    If n >= 1 Then
        For numtimes = 1 To n
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what will you copy, all sheets selected or only first sheet?

Comment: if sheets to repeat copying, create a variable to store your sheets, and do select the sheets again from variable each time you finish copying your sheets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the code for your purpose:

```
Public Sub DuplicateSheetMultipleTimes()
    Dim n As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    n = InputBox("How many copies of the selected sheets do you want to make?")

    Dim mySheets As sheets
    Set mySheets = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    If n >= 1 Then
        For numtimes = 1 To n
            mySheets.Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.sheets(Worksheets.Count)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```